# Mvc Foolproof not working on mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foolproof-validation

I have an MVC3 application.

This is the model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [NotEqualTo("Answer1")]
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
}
```

I enabled the onubtrusive validation on the web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

And this on my _layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My problem here is the MvcFoolproof is not working. The mvc data annotation validation `Required` is working. What did I missed here? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser?

Comment: No, i don't have any errors on browser.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suppose you have included `using Foolproof;` in your model.

Second, I believe you might need this script too (for client-side validation to work properly) `<script src="/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js"></script>`.

Third, did you add the Foolproof package using NuGet? Your `packages.config` should contain something like `<package id="foolproof" version="0.9.4517" targetFramework="net45" />`.

Also, are you displaying any validation messages in the view? Are these being shown for the required properties, but not for the `NotEqualTo` attribute?

Last, are you displaying all those properties in the view correctly, using e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answer1)`? Unless Answer2 has something to compare to, it surely won't validate. And you're using the jQuery validate-call on the form?

Mostly shots in the dark here, but getting Foolproof working is usually just a click-and-go operation.